# Loading duplicates/ merging variables

Tags: netlogo

I'm loading animal data with a lot of duplicates which I'm trying to merge into one agent representing a single animal. The csv file looks like this:

Animal ID - Group ID

1          - A

2          - A

3          - A

4          - A

1          - B

2          - B

And for this example, i'm hoping to produce 4 unique animal agents that have a list of the groups they are associated with. Animal 1's list would be [A, B] and Animal 4's list would be just [A].

So far, I'm loading the csv using:

```
   csv:from-row file-read-line
   create-animal 1 [
        set Animal-ID item 0 data
        set group-ID item 1 data]


Which produces 6 animals with one group id each.

But how should I cull the duplicate animals?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a csv that looks like:

```
id, group
1,A
2,A
3,A
4,A
1,B
2,B
```

You can load the csv as a list, pull unique animals, then filter the original list using the unique animal ids to grab the unique groups to which that animal belongs:

```
extensions [ csv ]

breed [ animals animal ]

animals-own [ animal-id group-id ]

to setup 
  ca
  
  ; Load animal data as a list of lists, drop the headers
  let animalData but-first csv:from-file "exampleAnimals.csv"
  print animalData
  
  ; Get the unique animal ids
  let animalIds remove-duplicates map [ i -> first i ] animalData
  print animalIds
  
  foreach animalIds [ id ->
    create-animals 1 [
      
      ; Set the id
      set animal-id id
      
      ; Filter the animal data by the id of the current animal
      let filtered filter [ row -> first row = id ] animalData
         
      ; Map to pull the group id as a list and assign to the animal
      set group-id map [ i -> last i ] filtered
      
      fd 1
    ]    
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

Hope that helps!

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to load in more columns of information in addition to group-id and assign them as more owned variables to the animal-id. Can you clarify how you select that the 2nd (vs 3rd, 4th, etc) is the one that should be used to pull the data? This arrangement seems to always pull the final column of info.

Comment: Is it where you use LAST in the phrase [i -> last i]? Could I swap in item 3 or similar to select other columns?

Comment: @AndrewYoak yes, exactly correct! Change up `set group-id map [ i -> last i ] filtered` to something like  `set group-id map [ i -> item 3 i ] filtered` to choose the column you need.